# Error "xm007 bad command argument 11" while reading emails from Outlook

Tags: c#, email, imap, outlook

I am working on EMAIL service and trying to get emails using **IMAP** **Ae.net.mail**, I am able to read the emails from **GMAIL** comfortably but when i try to do it for **Outlook express** it throws an exception as given below

**Error :**

> xm007 bad command argument 11

The code is given below for authentication which work fine

```
ImapClient ic = new ImapClient("outlook.office365.com", MailBoxID, Password, 
AuthMethods.Login, 993), true);

IMAPService im = new IMAPService();
im.LoadExchangeEmail(ic, dtEmailServer.Rows[i]);
```

Now, when i am trying to read email it gives me an exception as i mentioned above

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;    
using AE.Net.Mail;
using AE.Net.Mail.Imap;
using EmailDownloadService.Library;

namespace EmailDownloadService
{
    public class IMAPService
    {
        public void LoadExchangeEmail(ImapClient ic, DataRow Dt)
        {
            try
            {
                ic.SelectMailbox("Inbox");
                Lazy<MailMessage>[] mm = ic.SearchMessages(SearchCondition.SentSince(Convert.ToDateTime("1/10/2016 11:48:59 AM")), false, true)                         
                InsertIMAP ObjectIMAPInsert = new InsertIMAP();
                ObjectIMAPInsert.InsertEmail(mm, Dt);

                #region "Get email code"
                //foreach (Lazy<MailMessage> message in mm)
                //{
                //    MailMessage m = message.Value;
                //    string FromAddress= m.From.Address;                    
                //}
                #endregion

                ic.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorHandling.ErrorLog(string.Format("Method:LoadIMAP, LineNumber:{0}, Source:{1}, Message:{2}", ex.StackTrace, ex.Source, ex.Message));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here in this code when i am trying to execute

```
Lazy<MailMessage>[] mm = ic.SearchMessages(SearchCondition.SentSince(Convert.ToDateTime("1/10/2016 11:48:59 AM")), false, true)
```

it throws an exception like

> xm007 bad command argument 11

Can anybody guide to solve this?

Comment: The IMAP date-time syntax is DQUOTE date-day-fixed "-" date-month "-" date-year SP time SP zone DQUOTE; make sure you follow that. No slashes, no AM, no PM and no flexibility.

Comment: UID SEARCH BEFORE/SINCE is even simpler: DAY-MONTH-YEAR, only.  No times, no zones, and month is an abbreviation from Jan/Feb/Mar/Apr/May/Jun/Jul/Aug/Sep/Oct/Nov/Dec, I think.

Comment: @arnt I tried but couldn't resolve my issue, can you please give me an example how do i write Date for today?

Comment: @Max I tried but couldn't resolve my issue,  i would like to how do you write that for today's date, i need an example.

Comment: Oh please... 12-jan-2016

Comment: @arnt
Here is my code where i changed
'Lazy<MailMessage>[] mm = ic.SearchMessages(SearchCondition.SentSince(Convert.ToDateTime("12-jan-2016")), false, true);'
still is is showing me an error, I need to convert that to Datetime and when i convert it to DateTime appends Time by default, it doesn't accept the  string format.

Comment: The problem is that the IMAP library formats the DateTime incorrectly. You'll either need to change the code in the library, or, better yet, switch to an IMAP library that isn't broken such as my [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) library.